# Is Schema in Oracle is equivalent to Database in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2012, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle database and I wanted to create a database in Oracle. I followed this link to create a database:

http://www.fehily.com/books/createdb/createdb_oracle_11g_2.html

In Microsoft SQL Server, when we create a database, we use the `create database` command and the database creation is instantaneous [within fraction of seconds], but the Database Tool as described in link above took couple of minutes to create the database. Is database creation in Oracle this much slower?

Searching more about it, I have a feeling that this database created using above tool in Oracle is not equivalent to the database we create in SQL Server. Rather, the schema/user in oracle is appearing to be equivalent to database in SQL Server. Is it true?

So, If I want multiple databases in Oracle, do I create a single database and then multiple schemas inside that single database? And then are those multiple Schemas are my databases?

I am very much confused about all this. Can someone please refer me to a nice article/book that explains these things in oracle in detail?

Comment: When comes to details, there is no exact equivalence in either way. You might say that Oracle schema = MS SQL database. But then you may notice that you can not perform PITR(Point in time recovery) of Oracle schema, while you can restore a single MS SQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most purposes, yes you would indeed map a SQL server database to an Oracle schema (=user).

The term "database" in Oracle does not mean the same as in SQL Server. An Oracle "database" (from a technical point of view) is more like a SQL Server instance/installation, rather than a "database" in SQL Server.

SQL Server has two levels of namespace: database and schema. Whereas Oracle only has a single level of namespaces: a schema (which has a 1:1 relation to a user)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server and Oracle both support Schema.

A Schema is like a new database but it is not a new database

Maybe you are confused, **Mysql doesn't support schemas** but **SQL server offers full support for it**.

In mysql your database is a schema, to only difference is that it doesn't support multi schemas

For the part of creating multi databases or a single database if multiple schemas it all depend in your specific situation, **you should test thinks like performance and how much money you want to spend**, a multi database approach can be very expensive unlike a multi Schema approach