# Oracle SQL Developer and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I was following along with a Youtube tutorial on a Visual Studio and SQL connection. But in the Youtube video, it uses Microsoft SQL Server which is different from the one I'm using. There is a step that he did, but I could not find it in my Oracle SQL Developer.

He signed in with username and password and from his connection he found in the "Connection" bar on the left of the screen, a "database" folder then he right clicked it and chose "new database". In my Oracle I don't have this "database"  folder, I have "database links" which seems different when I click it. if you know how to find this same folder please help.

Comment: I don't believe the Oracle SQL Developer tool allows you to create a new database. I think you'll have to use a more traditional Oracle method. How you do it will depend on your Oracle server and the client tools you have available to you. Did you install the Oracle server locally? (Also: note that Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server are really quite different, especially at the administration level, so you may want to find a tutorial that's closer to your situation.)

Comment: I found out that in the youtube video he added a new database to create a table and he added rows and columns for his registration info.Isn't that possible in Oracle?

Comment: It's all possible in an Oracle database server, and some of it may be possible through the Oracle SQL Developer GUI client's interface, but I'm not sure creating a database can be done through SQL Developer, at least in a graphical way. You may be able to do it in a friendly(ish) way through the Oracle Database Configuration Assistant.

Comment: You can also share the YouTube link.

Answer (score 3):

The term 'database' means very different things in Oracle and SQL Server. In SQL Server it means something like a user account. In Oracle, a [database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-CF765A7D-9429-4901-BF33-36E0B0220293) is the whole installation, with data files, the lot. It's not something you do lightly with a click of a button for a SQL tutorial.

To run the tutorial in Oracle, you probably need to create a [user](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html), not a [database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE.html).

[Is Schema in Oracle is equivalent to Database in Microsoft SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097846/is-schema-in-oracle-is-equivalent-to-database-in-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: In SQL Server, a database is a database. But in SQL Server, there's a difference between a *user* and a *login*. That might be what you're thinking about.